# Ionic React build without minification

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I am trying to run the script

```html
ionic build
```

But the generated build version is always with --production flag. Thus my js/ts code is minified and not suitable for debugging. Do you know a way to build in dev mode?

[output of "ionic build"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgqWN.png)

The command "ionic build -- --mode development" which seems to work for Vue does not seem to work for React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic React uses [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) under the hood.  This means that you can use CRA build commands instead of Ionic.

As [described in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/25e6233aeb1b4f0cdb8d8366e54a3977), you need to enable profiling mode for CRA to get unminified output.

You can do this with the command `react-scripts build -- --profile`.

To make it easier, you can add a command to `scripts` in your `package.json` like:

```
   "build-profile": "react-scripts build -- --profile",
```

Comment: I deleted the build folder, and did "npm run build -- --profile" but the output looks still the same.. it is one huge file with unreadable code. thanks anyway!

Comment: @tjhannes What you should get are, for example, in the `js` folder, several dozen js files with random names and corresponding `.map` files.  You can then debug these files using the browser dev tools, which can read the source maps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Debugging with XCode or Android Studio is thus not possible?

Comment: @tjhannes You can debug capacitor plugins and such with XCode/Android Studio but for the webapp part you will generally debug in the browser: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging